# Remove "start" tag in mp3 file

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, metadata

I am trying to concatenate two MP3 files using the following command.

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:19 Protein Drink (2007-10-21 Indianapolis IN).mp3|20 Sewing Machine (2007-10-21 Indianapolis IN).mp3" -acodec copy "19 Protein Drink - Sewing Machine (2007-10-21 Indianapolis IN).mp3"
```

I keep getting a break/gap/silence in the concatenated file between the two on playback. I would like this to be gapless (given that there is a transition between the 2 songs). When I query info on the file there is a "start" tag in the Duration metadata of both files (example below - currently set to "0.025056").

Is there a tool that can remove this tag/metadata?

```
$ ffmpeg -i 19\ Protein\ Drink\ \(2007-10-21\ Indianapolis\ IN\).mp3 
ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.4 --enable-shared --
enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --
enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-
  libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, mp3, from '19 Protein Drink (2007-10-21 Indianapolis IN).mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : Protein Drink (2007-10-21 Indianapolis IN)
    artist          : Widespread Panic
    album_artist    : Widespread Panic
    album           : Driving Songs 02 - Fall 2007
    track           : 19
    date            : 2007
    genre           : Rock
    copyright       : 2007, Widespread Panic
  Duration: 00:05:27.05, start: 0.025056, bitrate: 257 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.98r
  Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 500x460 [SAR 1:1 DAR 25:23], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      comment         : Cover (front)
```

Comment: The `start` is not a tag. It likely indicates codec delay. Try with the [concat](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#concat-1) demuxer instead, although you may, in the end, need to use the [concat](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#concat-3) filter and re-encode.